# "was having" vs " had"

Tags: tense, past-tense

Which sentence is right?

> She had lung cancer for 6 months and the imaging studies showed a left lung mass.
>
> She was having left lung cancer for 6 months and the imaging studies showed a left lung mass.

Comment: Why are you considering the second example? Since the problem existed in the past, past tense should be enough. When using *was having*, some additional detail needs to follow the statement, as in "I *was eating* dinner when the phone rang", though it doesn't work in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**was having cancer** would not be idiomatic. Use the simple present or simple past when speaking of a malady or disease:

**To have** in that usage means "to suffer from".

> She **had mumps** when she was a child.
>
> She cannot come out and play. She **has a fever**.

However, for very brief bodily malfunctions, those which manifest as episodes,  we do use the present-continuous to indicate either that an episode is underway now or that the episodes are recurring or that the state is continual:

> He is having a muscle spasm.
>
> She is having less frequent convulsions since starting that medication.